# How to find the IP adress of my EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-eks, amazon-vpc

I have created an EKS cluster and deployed an API. My API needs to connect to a database that is not in AWS. In order to allow my API to use this database, I must authorize it's IP address in a whitelist. My problem is : I don't know how to get this IP adress since applications can be re-deployed and IP adresses can change... I'm not very familiar with networking notions and any detailed help can be very helpful since I don't only want the solution but also to understand how it works..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`My subnets are public...`

You can associate an Elastic IP address with the worker node, adjust the security group where applicable, then specify `nodeSelector` in your spec to run the special pod on the node. Finally you add the EIP to the whitelist.

Comment: My subnets are public and I'm not in the case that you provided :/

Comment: Checkout the updated answer.